# How do I get blocks to display in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm sure this is a very simple question, but I'm new to Drupal and haven't found a solution by the traditional methods of Googling and searching the Drupal home site, so please indulge me.

I've just installed Drupal 7 and am using the Bartik theme.

When I click Structure > Blocks there are a bunch of blocks at the bottom of the page which you can drag to a position corresponding to a region of the page template (Footer, Sidebar 1 etc).

However, when I assign a block to a region, whether by dragging, using the dropdown menu or using the configuration menu against the block, it does not save the assignation.

The block does not appear in the assigned region and when I return to the blocks page, those blocks are back at the bottom of the page, not assigned to a region.

The only blocks that I can make stick are ones that I create myself.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for a solution?

Thank you.

Comment: just curious, how many blocks are there on your block page?

Comment: @FunkyDude - there are 13 in the "Disabled" section at the bottom. My problem is getting them into one of the regions.

Comment: i mean total. few dozens or more?

Comment: @FunkyDude - the theme has 15 regions and my site has a total of 18 blocks available, of which 5 have been assigned to a region. Of these five, two were assigned automatically (content and system help) on installation and the other three were created by me and just contain text/html.

Comment: I had a similar problem with not being able to save block configuration on block page. it turned out to be the max_input_vars limit was hit on the block page. i don't think this is the case for you though, unless your max_input_vars is unusually low.

Comment: It sounds like you're doing everything right. My first guess is that there is an error saving these changes. Any clues in Drupal's Recent Log at `/admin/reports/dblog`? If not, I'd go looking to the server log, probably the error_log somewhere in the hosts log section.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> However, when I assign a block to a region, whether by dragging, using
>   the dropdown menu or using the configuration menu against the block,
>   it does not save the assignation.

It sounds as if you didn't click "save blocks" after assigning a block to a region - did you? There is a button on the bottom of the page - just below the blocks.

Comment: Hi @yan - yes, I did click the "save blocks" button, it just didn't save them!

Comment: Maybe you have a memory issue - have you tried [increasing your memory_limit](https://drupal.org/node/207036)? Also check if there are error messages in your logs.